# Visual Studio 2010 C++ CLR Debugging Windows: How to override 'Value' part?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, c++-cli

I did a research on web and cannot find anything so maybe you know a way to solve my problem. 
I am using MS VS 2010, and I use VS C++ (only CLR).. Let's say I have a class smt like this:

```
class A
{
public:
int x;
float a;
char* str;
};
```

While debugging my application, I open "Locals Window"  and I see my variable name, value and Type. I would like to change (write) something to my value part. Like I habe a class A object a:

```
Name          Value                             Type
a             x: 4  a: 2.03f  str: 'Hello!'     A
```

I hope this was a clear example. I want to override value part in locals, autos ... windows.. Any way to do it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class is a managed class then you can decorate it with a [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx). If it is unmanaged, which your example seems to be, then you need to edit a file called autoexp.dat. There's a fairly old article on MSDN about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730838.aspx), I have done this a long time ago and remember it was a pain to get working. Also, there is a bug filed on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/622315/autoexp-dat-visualizers-ignored-in-c-cli) that autoexp.dat doesn't work for C++/CLI projects in VS 2010, though I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: this is kinda late reply, but thank you. Yeah I did more research and find that I need to edit file autoexp.dat.. And I see that's why painful.. I hope there would be an easir solution :)